# auto check radio buttons using jstl

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, html

I have tried lots of options to auto check the radio buttons based on the angularjs value

I have assigned `$scope.loyaltyType = "points";`

Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="radio-option-select">
  <div>
    <span>
      <input type="radio"  name="loyaltyType" id="ex1" ${loyaltyType=='punchcard'?'checked':'checked'}>
      <label for="ex1">Punch Card </label>
    </span>
    <span>
      <input type="radio"  name="loyaltyType" id="ex2" ${loyaltyType=='points'?'checked':'checked'}>
      <label for="ex2">Points</label>
    </span>
    <span>
      <input type="radio" name="loyaltyType"  id="ex3" ${loyaltyType=='percentage'?'checked':'checked'}> 
      <label for="ex3">% Of Purchase Reward Voucher</label>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Help me out to find if any other alternative way exist?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use the ng-model directive of angular ?

Something like this :

```
$scope.loyaltyType = "punchcard"

<input type="radio" value="punchcard" ng-model="loyaltyType">
<input type="radio" value="points" ng-model="loyaltyType">
<input type="radio" value="percentage" ng-model="loyaltyType">
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of the input is set by `ng-model` and `ng-checked` directives

So, that the way:

```
<div class="radio-option-select">
  <div>
    <span>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="loyaltyType.punchcard" ng-checked="loyaltyType.punchcard">
      <label for="ex1">Punch Card </label>
    </span>
    <span>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="loyaltyType.points" ng-checked="loyaltyType.points">
      <label for="ex2">Points</label>
    </span>
    <span>
      <input type="radio" ng-model="loyaltyType.percentage" ng-checked="loyaltyType.percentage"> 
      <label for="ex3">% Of Purchase Reward Voucher</label>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in your controller, set the value:

```
$scope.loyaltyType = {};
$scope.loyaltyType.points = true;
```

Try in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jagow4ec/)

Comment: I'm able to get the checked="checked" in the HTML. But with the CSS image of radio button I'm getting the problem. It is not showing Clicked.
Can you suggest how to show the button clicked with the CSS image.
  @valverde93